# Is there a way to "fill in" concave vertices?

Tags: modeling

I'm not at my computer so can't show what I mean with an image, but say I had an edge loop in the shape of a 5-pointed star, does Blender have the means to fill in the concave vertices (or pull them out) so that said star becomes a pentagon?

Comment: try `Ctrl+V -> Convex Hull`  with the 10 verts selected.  then remove the newly generated inner edge, that will give you a hexagon outline.

Comment: @zeffii Thanks, that had the effect I was after but unfortunately was quite messy geometrically. Perhaps if I play around with combining it with a subsurf etc I'll get the result I'm after. Thanks again.

Comment: something could be scripted , but you'd need to flesh out your question to make it answerable and useful to others

Comment: No problem. When I get the time I'll repost with my actual issue.